# Python. Модуль tkinter. Ограничение возможности использования основного окна, если открыто неосновное

Tags: python, tkinter

Работаю над программой, модуль tkinter, и вот в чём суть. Есть основное окошко, в поле ввода вводится текст. Текст обязан быть читаемым числом (float, int), если условие не выполняется, должно открываться новое окошко, поверх старого, и блокировать возможность использования старого, пока не будет закрыто новое (как при сохранении файла на windows, то есть пока окошко сохранения открыто, с файлом невозможно взаимодействовать), если что, проверка числа не нужна, просто нужно создать малое окно поверх основного, блокирующее основное при невыполнении ранее сказанного условия. Так же желательно, чтоб программа смогла определить точное положение основного окна на экране, и в соответствии с этим сгенерировать малое окно на определённых координатах над основным, как бы перекрывая его. Переменная основного окна - r, малого - window_er.

[image: куски кода, скопировать его не могу]

Comment: Приветствуем! И в чем загвоздка?

Comment: просто не знаю, как реализовать вышеописанную задумку - блокировка одного tkinter-окна, пока существует другое, прям как при сохранении файла на ПК, когда нужно указать путь и дать название

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать это, можно применить функцию `r.grab_set()` и `r.grab_release()`, чтобы вернуть обратно. Если помог, то отметьте пожалуйста ответ как верный.

Comment: нет, не получилось. если просто чутка сдвинуть окно ошибки, то программой можно пользоваться. а это недопустимо